# VB6 Random Number Generation Seed Scope

Tags: random, vb6, scope, random-seed

What is the scope of the Randomize(seed) function? The way this code is written will the random number generator be seeded with a value of 20 when generate is called from myfunction? Does the randomize function change a global variable or some local variable?

Thanks for any help!

```
Function myfunction()
    Call seed()
    Call generate()
End Function

Function seed()
    Randomize (20)
End Function

Function generate()
    Dim X As Integer
    X = CInt(100*Rnd)
End Function
```

Comment: `Randomize()` has application scope. It just needs to be seeded once at startup, typically in `Form_Load()` or a similar initialization event. You could use a `Static` boolean in your `generate()` function also, to make sure `Randomize()` is called the first time you go to generate a number.

Comment: There isn't much reason to pass a value like 20 either.  Just use the `Randomize` *statement* by itself.  The parentheses used above are just silly too, almost as bad as *functions* that don't return values.

Answer (score 0):

If you call Randomize with explicit value or do not call Randomize at all you will get the same sequence by every start of the program. Try:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sText As String

sText = ""
For i = 1 To 10
  sText = sText & CInt(100 * Rnd(10)) & vbCrLf
Next i

MsgBox sText
```

But of course sometimes it could be wanted result...